# Error when run artisan command in old projects and working fine for newly crated projects of Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, illuminate-container

Getting uncertain error i.e

```
[![Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in D:\xampp\htdocs\pilotRH\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Arr.php on line 388][1]][1]
```

When I run artisan command in my old projects and then I test the same case by creating new projects of Laravel artisan command working fine there.

Comment: What PHP and Laravel version are you running?

Comment: CLI is showing 7.0.8 PHP version and phpinfo() is showing 7.1.29
Laravel version is 5.7

Comment: [Laravel 5.7 requires PHP >= 7.1.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/installation), so you'll need to switch the PHP cli version.

Comment: after doing @aynber said, do composer update

Comment: Thank you @aynber

Answer (score 0):

It was due to confliction of PHP version in apache and composer. 
I uninstall the old version of composer and then install the latest version of the composer from  https://getcomposer.org/download/

If you are using Ubuntu then you need to upgrade or uninstall it using commands

It works for me :)